# C# Async Foreach

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, foreach, stock

I'm busy working on a stock tracker app in Windows Forms for funsies. In an attempt to optimize my code, I decided to rewrite the main function that keeps everything up to date. Instead of scourging all controls for the correct one, I figured it would be easier to select the right row and work from there. Issue is: It keeps skipping over the task I want to run, and doesn't update it anymore. I've tried a bunch of things I've found on the internet, but I can't get it to work. So I reverted back to the simplest form of my original code to see if you guys maybe have an idea. Here is the essence of it all:

```
        public async void KeepUpdatingEverything(List<object> positionInfo, List<string> tickerList)
        {
            foreach (string ticker in tickerList)
            {
                //code that gets the right row
                List<object> priceInfo = await GetStockPrices(ticker));
                //code that updates all the labels
            }
        }
```

The idea is that when the KeepUpdating function is called, it checks the list with tickers, gets the price for each ticker and subsequently updates all the correlating labels. But I can't seem to get it to work because it keeps skipping over the async call. Any ideas?

KeepUpdatingEverything is called once as the first ticker is entered, after that it just keeps updating the ticker list.

```
        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ticker;
            using (Prompt prompt = new Prompt("Enter the ticker symbol", "Add ticker"))
            {
                ticker = prompt.Result;
                ticker = ticker.ToUpper();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ticker))
                {

                    using (Prompt prompt2 = new Prompt("Enter your volume", "Add ticker"))
                    {
                        if (Int32.TryParse(prompt2.Result, out int volume) == true)
                        {
                            using (Prompt prompt3 = new Prompt("Enter your buy price", "Add ticker"))
                            {
                                if (Double.TryParse(prompt3.Result, out double buyPrice) == true)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        List<object> priceInfo = await GetStockPrices(ticker);
                                        FillTickerLabel(ticker);

                                        List<object> positionInfo = GetPositionVars(ticker, volume, buyPrice, Convert.ToDouble(priceInfo[1]));
                                        FillPositionLabel(ticker, priceInfo[0].ToString(), positionInfo);

                                        List<object> changeInfo = GetChangeVars(ticker, priceInfo);
                                        FillChangeLabels(ticker, priceInfo[0].ToString(), changeInfo);

                                        List<string> tickerList = new List<string>();
                                        tickerList.Add(ticker);
                                        if (tickerList.Count <= 1)
                                        {
                                            _cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();
                                            _runningTask = StartTimer(() => KeepUpdatingEverything(positionInfo, tickerList), _cancellationToken);

                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("Ticker does not exist, or entered incorrect value somewhere else");
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    MessageBox.Show("You did not enter one of the textboxes correctly");
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("You did not enter one of the textboxes correctly");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You did not enter one of the textboxes correctly");
                }
            }
        }
```

Finally, the StartTimer function:

```
        private async Task StartTimer(Action action, CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource)
        {
            try
            {
                while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationTokenSource.Token);
                    action();
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        }
```

Comment: Where/how is the `KeepUpdatingEverything` method invoked? Also are you aware of this article? [Avoid async void](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void).

Comment: `_runningTask = StartTimer(() => KeepUpdatingEverything...` <== What is the `StartTimer` method doing?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Starts a timer to run KeepUpdatingEverything every 5 seconds. I checked the article, but changing it to a Task type didn't make any difference. I'll edit the full StartTimer code in the main post

Comment: *"It keeps skipping over the task I want to run, and doesn't update it anymore."* <== What do you mean with "keeps skipping over the task"?

Comment: As soon as it reaches the `List<object> priceInfo = await GetStockPrices(ticker));` line it jumps to the `while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)` line, and then back to the for each loop. I wish I understood better how to write proper error handling for this.

Comment: Do you know if the `await GetStockPrices(ticker)` throws an exception? In that case my expectation is that the exception would escalate into an application crash. Unless some additional error-swallowing code exists (empty `catch` blocks), that you have omitted from the question.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias It doesn't crash, it just jumps back to the `while (!cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)` and starts the action again.

Comment: Does it throw an exception though?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Unless something happens that I'm unaware about, it doesn't

Comment: Why is it a problem to jump back in the `while` loop? There is an `await Task.Delay(5000)` inside, so the action will not be invoked more frequently than every 5 seconds.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Well... The issue is that I need it to actually run the GetStockPrices function, but it just skips over it

Comment: I guess that by "skips over" you mean that the `GetStockPrices` method is not invoked. How do you know that it's not invoked? Do you deduce it by not seeing the UI being updated?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias If I step through the code in the debugger line by line I can see it skips over it. Also the variable isn't filled, and the UI doesn't update. So everything points into the direction that the code isn't executed (or that there's something wrong with it that doesn't lead to a crash).

Answer (score 1):

`async void` means that you don't return a task that the caller can `await`.

You should use `async Task` like this

```
public async Task KeepUpdatingEverything(List<object> positionInfo, List<string> tickerList)
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried this but it didn't seem to make a difference. It still cancels performing the task.

Answer (score -1):

Update to Hans answer.
You need to `await` the call in parent method.

`await KeepUpdatingEverything(...)`

And it will wait until finish.

Btw is not the best way to `await` inside foreach.
It will be easier to take all Tasks result into a list or an array and `await` them all.

`await Tasks.WhenAll(tasks);`

Comment: Tried this, but didn't seem to make a difference either sadly